# Excluding overlapped period in doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine, period

I have `Product` and `Booking` entity and I'm trying to select products that aren't already booked in a given period. In other words, to select available products during a given period.

To make myself understandable, see the schema below. I only want to select product that have a booking like #1 or #5 since it is available. If a product has some booking like #2, #3, #4, #6, don't select it since it is not available.

Each `|--|` represents a period, left side the `startAt` field and at the right side the `endAt` field.

```
Past                                              Futur 
|----------------------------------------------------->
                     Given period
                   |--------------|
     1             .              .
|---------|        .              .
                 2 .              .
             |-----+-|            .
                   .      3       .
                   .   |-----|    .
                   .              . 4
                   .            |-+-----|
                   .              .             5
                   .              .        |---------|
                   .       6      .
             |-----+--------------+-----|
                   .              .
```

My guess was to create a query like this:

```php
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAvailableProducts(\DateTimeInterface $startAt, \DateTimeInterface $endAt): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->addSelect('b')
            ->join('p.bookings', 'b')
            ->andWhere('b.startAt > :endAt OR b.endAt < :startAt')
            ->setParameter('startAt', $startAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('endAt', $endAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

But when the `andWhere()` condition is met with #1 or #5 in the schema, the database (MYSQL 5.6) select this product even if #2, #3, #4 or #6 exist.

I am a little bit stuck with this query, and I feel I am going the wrong way so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your condition looks ok, [see demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51f4c0896eb1547b21eb260f0b4bebddfae28460). Can you just share an SQL fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @nice_dev You can see my fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9ca68/1)

Comment: @nice_dev The expected output in the fiddle should be no result since there is some bookings overlapping the given period. But with this query, it shows me the product because #1 and #5 met the condition.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, results are correct. `['2022-01-05','2022-01-15']` does not overlap with `['2021-11-05','2021-11-10']` and `['2022-02-01','2022-02-15']`. Hence, they both are retrieved.

Comment: @nice_dev The whole point of this query is to determine if a product is available for booking. If a booking exists during the given period `['2022-01-05', '2022-01-15']` then the product is not available. So yes, results are correct for this query but it's not the right query. I'm looking for a query that outputs only available product but I'm stuck while doing it.

Comment: When I say 'available', I mean a product that hasn't any booking during the given period.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that using a subquery with `NOT EXISTS ()` instead of inner join is the best way to do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM product p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM booking b WHERE (
    (b.startAt between '2022-01-05 00:00:00' and '2022-01-15 00:00:00') OR 
    (b.endAt between '2022-01-05 00:00:00' and '2022-01-15 00:00:00') OR 
    ('2022-01-05 00:00:00' between b.startAt and b.endAt)
  ) AND b.product_id = p.id
) IN (1,2);
```

Here, the subquery find conflicting bookings (thanks @nice_dev in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69724517/12528090)).

Doctrine repository:

```php
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    private EntityRepository $bookingRepository;

    public function __construct(BookingRepository $bookingRepository)
    {
        $this->bookingRepository = $bookingRepository;
    }

    public function getAvailableProducts(\DateTimeInterface $startAt, \DateTimeInterface $endAt): array
    {
        $bookingQueryBuilder = $this->bookingRepository->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->andWhere('b.startAt between :startAt and :endAt OR b.endAt between :startAt and :endAt OR :startAt between b.startAt and b.endAt')
            ->andWhere('b.product = p')
        ;

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->andWhere(sprintf('not exists (%s)', $bookingQueryBuilder->getDQL()))
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A product may/may not have bookings in a given period. To detect overlaps or collisions, you need to check for 3 conditions at the maximum:

- Current row start date is in between selected date period
- Current row end date is in between selected date period
- Start date of selected period is in between current row's start date and end date.

**Raw SQL Query:**

```
SELECT count(*) as 'booked_count'
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN booking b ON p.id = b.product_id 
WHERE (
        (b.startAt between '2022-01-05 00:00:00' and '2022-01-15 00:00:00') OR 
        (b.endAt between '2022-01-05 00:00:00' and '2022-01-15 00:00:00') OR 
        ('2022-01-05 00:00:00' between b.startAt and b.endAt)
    ) 
AND p.id IN (1,2);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9ca68/9)

**Doctrine QueryBuilder:**

```
<?php

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAvailableProducts(\DateTimeInterface $startAt, \DateTimeInterface $endAt): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->addSelect('count(b.*) as cnt')
            ->join('p.bookings', 'b')
            ->where('b.startAt between :startAt and :endAt')
            ->orWhere('b.endAt between :startAt and :endAt')
            ->orWhere(':startAt between b.startAt and b.endAt')
            ->setParameter('startAt', $startAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('endAt', $endAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

**Note:** This way you can check with the *count* of the retrieved records and move ahead accordingly.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong but according to your sql fiddle, your query retrieves overlaped products (product that has booking collisions) while I am looking for the reverse. I understand I should count the records and if the number of records equals 0, then there is no collision. But if I add `->andHaving('COUNT(b) = 0')` I retrieve null product... Thanks for investigate with me!

Comment: @Benjamin Yes, it is deliberately done this way, so the count of records retrieved should tell you whether there are any bookings made or not in the given period. I will check with doctrine docs again to add it in the queryBuilder

Comment: @Benjamin I updated my answer. I just changed the addSelect to `->addSelect('count(b.*) as cnt')`. See if this works ok(since I am not into Doctrine stuff)

Comment: Can you change `count(b.*)` by `count(b)`? It is a syntax error for Doctrine.

Comment: I get what you want to do but it isn't fiting my project. The `getAvailableProducts()` method should only return available products. In my application, I don't use `->getQuery()->getResult()`, just the query builder. The bundle I use must receive `products[]` from this query.

Comment: You can see in my answer how I handle the query ;) Thanks for searching with me!

Comment: @Benjamin Glad to see that you figured that out. Sorry I am not really into doctrine query builder, so couldn't help you much with the syntax.